# Key-based Publish/Subscribe in Redis

Tags: redis, ipc, interprocess, distributed-system, inter-process-communicat

I'm building a web application which needs to forward user-generated input to a parser for validation. After a bit of investigation, Redis seems like a reliable tool to build a communication layer for those two applications.

At first, I looked into the Publish/Subscribe functionality of Redis, which seemed perfect for the job. Then I realized that this approach is not capable of using keys to uniquely identify a data set forwarded to the parser or the response of the parser itself.

I was thinking of the following solution: The input data could be written into a standard key value schema, at which the parser detects the new tuple, performs the validation and replaces the value with the parser response. After that, the web application detects the value change and reads the field, displaying the parser output to the user.

Is there any mechanism provided by Redis to allow notifactions for creation of new tuples and changes of the data field in those? If not, how would you implement this scenario?

Thanks in advance.